# How to Normalize data with NaN values in python

Tags: python, dataframe, normalize

The data I am using has some null values and I want to impute the Null values using knn Imputation. In order to effectively impute I want to Normalize the data.

```
normalizer = Normalizer() #from sklearn.preprocessing
normalizer.fit_transform(data[num_cols]) #columns with numeric value
```

Error: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

So how do I normalize data that is having NaN

Comment: You can write your own function to normalize the data

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest not to use normalize in sklearn as it does not deal with NaNs. You can simply use below code to normalize your data.

```
df['col']=(df['col']-df['col'].min())/(df['col'].max()-df['col'].min())
```

Above method ignores NaNs while noramlizing the data

Comment: How does one denormalize after using this formula?

Comment: what exactly you want to do? If you want to get back original values save it in variable. I suggest you should ask new question with details.

Comment: Oh sorry, what I meant was... imagine you normalize the 'y' value. So, after prediction the 'yhat' will also be normalized. Without using MinMaxScaler, but using your formula, how do I denormlize the 'yhat' value?

Answer (score 3):

sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer is not about 0 mean, 1 stdev normalization like the other answers to date. Normalizer() is about scaling rows to unit norm e.g. to [improve clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-text-plot-document-clustering-py) or the original questions imputation. You can read about the differences [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-all-scaling-py) and [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer). For scaling rows you could try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[  7,     4,   5,  7000],
              [  1,   900,   9,   nan],
              [  5, -1000, nan,   100],
              [nan,   nan,   3,  1000]])

#Compute NaN-norms
L1_norm = np.nansum(np.abs(A), axis=1)
L2_norm = np.sqrt(np.nansum(A**2, axis=1))
max_norm = np.nanmax(np.abs(A), axis=1)

#Normalize rows
A_L1 =  A / L1_norm[:,np.newaxis] # A.values if Dataframe
A_L2 =  A / L2_norm[:,np.newaxis]
A_max = A / max_norm[:,np.newaxis]

#Check that it worked
L1_norm_after = np.nansum(np.abs(A_L1), axis=1)
L2_norm_after = np.sqrt(np.nansum(A_L2**2, axis=1))
max_norm_after = np.nanmax(np.abs(A_max), axis=1)

 In[182]: L1_norm_after
Out[182]: array([1., 1., 1., 1.])

 In[183]: L2_norm_after
Out[183]: array([1., 1., 1., 1.])

 In[184]: max_norm_after
Out[184]: array([1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

If Google brought you here (like me) and you want to normalize columns to 0 mean, 1 stdev using the estimator API you can use [sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler). It can handle NaNs (Tested on sklearn 0.20.2, I remember it didn't work on some older versions).

```
from numpy import nan, nanmean
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

A = [[  7,     4,   5,  7000],
     [  1,   900,   9,   nan],
     [  5, -1000, nan,   100],
     [nan,   nan,   3,  1000]]

scaler.fit(A)

In [45]: scaler.mean_
Out[45]: array([4.33333333,  -32.,    5.66666667, 2700.])

In [46]: scaler.transform(A)
Out[46]: array([[ 1.06904497,  0.04638641, -0.26726124,  1.40399977],
                [-1.33630621,  1.20089267,  1.33630621,         nan],
                [ 0.26726124, -1.24727908,         nan, -0.84893009],
                [        nan,         nan, -1.06904497, -0.55506968]])

In [54]: nanmean(scaler.transform(A), axis=0)
Out[54]: array([ 1.48029737e-16,  0.00000000e+00, -1.48029737e-16,0.00000000e+00])
```

Answer (score 1):

This method normalize all the columns to [0,1], and NaN remains being NaN

```
def norm_to_zero_one(df):
    return (df - df.min()) * 1.0 / (df.max() - df.min())
```

For example:

```
[In]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, np.nan, 30],
                   'B': [1, np.nan, 10, 5]})
df = df.apply(norm_to_zero_one)
[Out]
     A         B
0  0.0  0.000000
1  0.5       NaN
2  NaN  1.000000
3  1.0  0.444444
```

`df.max()` and `df.min()` return the max and min of each column.